# Multi_key as Hangul/English toogle hotkey doesn't work in 17.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, korean

Since my laptop doesn't have Hangul/English toggle hotkey, I'd been using the right alt key (`Multi_key`) as it until 17.04. But now as 17.10, it doesn't work, even though I have only Korean (Hangul) in Input Sources and added `Multi_key` to "Hangul toggle key" list in IBusHangul Setup. It just serves as a hotkey for European characters, like `Multi_key+a+e` = `æ`, `Multi_key+!+?` = `‽`, `Multi_key+"+"` = `¨`, etc. How can I fix this problem?

EDIT: Enabling "Hangul Mode" in the top bar doesn't let me type hangul. The problem might be a bug of `ibus-hangul` package. Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe indicates that your <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> key has been defined as the [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose). You need to pick some other key as the compose key (or simply disable the compose key mechanism, if you don't need it) to use <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> as a Hangul toggle.

Comment: I picked `Menu` key as the compose key, and Added `Alt_R` to the Hangul Toogle Key list, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @DannyuNDos: It works for me when the cursor is in a position ready for typing.

Comment: Oh, restarting the system solves the problem. Thank you very much.